# PHP: How does if($result = someFunction()) work?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm learning how to use MySQL in PHP and when learning how to call for an SQL query in the database I saw that the procedural method contained this if statement:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query))
```

What is this statement saying? What I think it says is:
 1. Set `$result` equal to `mysqli_query($link, $query)`.
 2. If `$result` is not null (i.e. the `mysqli_query` method returned something), execute the if block.
If what I'm thinking is true, is `$result` usable outside of the if block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same as

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if ($result) { // If $result is truthy
    // Stuff
}
```

And essentially means "*if the result from `mysqli_query` is truthy, then do something. If it fails, do not do it, as `$result` will be falsy.*".

According to the [`mysqli_query` documentation](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query):

> Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`.

Both a `mysqli_result` and `TRUE` are truthy, however `FALSE` is obviously not. Hence it only enters the `if` block if the query went alright.

Yes, `$result` will be available outside of the if query, just as in the above example.

[A live demo demonstrating an object converted to a bool (it will be `TRUE`)](https://eval.in/186646):

```
<?php

$object = (object)array('foo' => 'bar');

var_dump($object); // object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["foo"] => string(3) "bar" }

var_dump((bool)$object); // bool(true)
```

Comment: I'd add that `mysqli_query` returns a resource (which is truthy) on success.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers his question. OP's question seems to be more about the `if` statement

Comment: @true What do you think is asker's confusion if not this?

Comment: My query is a `SELECT` query, so will the if statement then also be true? Are objects true by default?

Comment: @StrongJoshua Your `$result` will be an `mysqli_result` object. Objects are not `true` by default, however they're `truthy` meaning if *converted* into a boolean, it would get the value `true`. Here's the [comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for PHP types and truthy values. You should look under *Loose comparisons with ==*. Resources and objects are also truthy. [**Here's a live demo demonstrating this**](https://eval.in/186646).

Comment: note: there's not really much point in actually doing a `(bool)` cast. And even when there's a use, I'd use double negation myself.

Comment: @JanDvorak Agreed - it was solely to demonstrate what an object would be if PHP were to convert it to a bool (which is similar to how truthy values work).

Answer (score 4):

> The result of an assignment operation is the assigned value.

That means: `=` is an *operator*, the *assignment operator* to be precise. It works like *`a = b`*, where the value of *`b`* is assigned to variable *`a`*. In the same way that the addition operator returns a number, e.g. `1 + 2` returns `3`, the assignment operation returns a value as well. The value it returns is the assigned value; in the case above the value of *`b`*.

That's why `$a = $b = $c` works.

> ```
> if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query))
> ```

This assigns the result of `mysqli_query($link, $query)` to `$result` and then tests the same value which was assigned with [the standard truthiness test, i.e. `== true`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

> is `$result` usable outside of the `if` block?

Yes, PHP does not have block scope, it only has *function scope*.

Comment: This is the most valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query($link, $query)` returns false on failure.

so by doing `if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query))`
you are saving the return value of `mysqli_query` into `$result` and checking if `$result` is false.
If it is not false, this means that `mysqli_query` has not failed and you can access the result in `$result`.

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    //success. YAY
}
else {
    //failed.
}
```